# Form a quadratic equation with the following details.

Tags: roots, quadratics

If $\alpha, \beta$ are the roots of the equation 
$
x^2 - px + q = 0
$
and $\alpha_1, \beta_1$ are the roots of the equation $x^2 - qx + p = 0$,

Form the quadratic equation whose roots are 
$$
\frac{1}{\alpha_1 \beta} + \frac{1}{\alpha \beta_1} and \frac{1}{\alpha_1 \alpha} + \frac{1}{\beta_1 \beta}
$$

Comment: Multiply & add the last two and express the results in terms of $p,q$

Comment: That's far too long a method... I wanted to check if there's something shorter... what you are telling is known to everyone. Its in the JEE package... time is limited there bruh.

Comment: I think the theorem of Vieta can help you.

Comment: $p= \alpha + \beta$ and $q=\alpha \cdot \beta$ from the first equation, and $q=\alpha _1 +\beta _1$ and $p=\alpha_1 \cdot \beta _1$ from the second.  Take it from there....

Comment: Have you got a solution in your exercise book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculation gives $$\left(\frac{1}{\alpha_1 \beta} + \frac{1}{\alpha \beta_1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{\alpha_1 \alpha} + \frac{1}{\beta_1 \beta}\right)=\frac{(\alpha +\beta)(\alpha_1+\beta_1)}{\alpha\alpha_1\beta\beta_1}=1$$ and similarly
$$\left(\frac{1}{\alpha_1 \beta} + \frac{1}{\alpha \beta_1}\right)*\left(\frac{1}{\alpha_1 \alpha} + \frac{1}{\beta_1 \beta}\right)=\frac{p^3+q^3-4pq}{(pq)^2}$$ Then the equation is 
$$(pq)^2X^2-(pq)^2X+p^3+q^3-4pq=0$$

Comment: Thanks... this looks real decent... but can there be a shorter method... that can help me in competitive exams... like we have to answer 30 questions in 90 minutes... and another 60 in physics + chemistry in 180 minutes...

Comment: This problem has a very easy theoretical solution and it is basically a problem of calculation, of good management of simplification of an algebraic expression.

Answer (score 2):

By Vieta's formulas:
$$\alpha+\beta=p; \alpha\beta=q;\\
\alpha_1+\beta_1=q; \alpha_1\beta_1=p.$$
The equation to be found: $X^2+BX+C=0$, whose roots must be:
$$\frac{1}{\alpha_1 \beta} + \frac{1}{\alpha \beta_1} \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \frac{1}{\alpha_1 \alpha} + \frac{1}{\beta_1 \beta}$$
The sum:
$$-B=\frac{1}{\alpha_1 \beta} + \frac{1}{\alpha \beta_1} + \frac{1}{\alpha_1 \alpha} + \frac{1}{\beta_1 \beta}=\frac{1}{\alpha_1}\cdot \frac{\alpha+\beta}{\alpha\beta}+\frac{1}{\beta_1}\cdot \frac{\alpha+\beta}{\alpha\beta}=\frac{\alpha+\beta}{\alpha\beta}\cdot \frac{\alpha_1+\beta_1}{\alpha_1\beta_1}=\cdots=1.$$
The product:
$$C=\left(\frac{1}{\alpha_1 \beta} + \frac{1}{\alpha \beta_1}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\alpha_1 \alpha} + \frac{1}{\beta_1 \beta}\right)=\frac{1}{\alpha_1^2\alpha\beta}+\frac{1}{\beta_1^2\alpha\beta}+\frac{1}{\alpha^2\alpha_1\beta_1}+\frac{1}{\beta^2\alpha_1\beta_1}=\\
\frac{1}{\alpha\beta}\cdot \frac{(\alpha_1+\beta_1)^2-2\alpha_1\beta_1}{\alpha_1^2\beta_1^2}+\frac{1}{\alpha_1\beta_1}\cdot \frac{(\alpha+\beta)^2-2\alpha\beta}{\alpha^2\beta^2}=\cdots=\\
\frac{q^3-2pq+p^3-2pq}{p^2q^2}.$$
Note: The triple dots to be filled by you.

Comment: I didn't know that those are "Vieta's formulas" though... thanks! got to know something new...

Comment: By your comparison of the two answers and accepting the other one, I see that you did not really know.

Comment: I'm sorry bruh... I had accepted your answer too... then the other one seemed shorted and I accepted it... In that process I guess yours was dis-selected... I am new to these forums and I guess only one answer can be selected... I've changed it back man... You've done the same thing too... He has skipped a few lines that's all... it wasn't to demean you...

Comment: Now I am glad to know that you are not surface learning. I used the triple dots and did not write the final form of equation as an exercise/practice for you. Good luck.

Comment: That's not funny... -_- .... Im asking stuff here... I obviously know how to form equations... Anyway... Thanks

Comment: The most important rule of this forum is the asker should show some effort towards solving his/her question. Otherwise the question may get downvotes and eventually close down. So, beware the rules! I am sorry if I sounded harsh. Good luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82452/discussion-between-saurabh000345-and-farruhota).